# Convert the output of CPU mask from 64 bit to 32 bit

Tags: bash

I have one script as per below which gives the output in 64 bit, but I want the output in 32 bit.

Code:

```
hk_cpumask="$(printf "%x\n" $hk_cpumask)"
```

Current output:

```
fffffeabfffffeab
```

Expected output:

```
fffffeab,fffffeab
```

Comment: And what have you tried? There are many possible approaches to that.

Comment: Add content of $hk_cpumask to your question.

Comment: Hi Cyrus,  the HK cpu mask for me is 0,1,3,5,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,35,37,39,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63

Comment: Hi @Quasímodo Can you tell me any of that as i did not understand how to change it.

Comment: For example, you tagged bash. In its man page, look for `${parameter:offset:length}`. It's one way to do it.

Comment: Hi Quasímodo, I tried but did not find anything relevent, Can you help me in this as i am new in bash so i dont have an idea how to change this script so that it can give me the output in 32bit instead of 64bit.

Comment: Hi,Can anyone help in this